# bokeh-server: command not found

Tags: bokeh

I have clone the source code from github and installed in the following way

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/quickstart.html#quick-installation

version

```
'0.11.0dev2-433-g96576eb'
```

Everything works fine, except for bokeh server

type in "bokeh server" in command line, get

```
bokeh-server: command not found
```

but "bokeh serve" does start the tornado server, which in documentation say Flask is used ?

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh had an older server `bokeh-server` command, which was Flask based. Unfortunately it did not scale well or meet the performance we wanted to achieve. As of version 0.11 there is a new `bokeh serve` command that is based on Tornado and a pure websocket protocol. It is easier to deploy and use, but the changes needed to support the new server and protocol were incompatible in fundamental ways with the old server, so the old `bokeh-server` command has been completely removed as of version 0.11 and later.

Bokeh server examples can be found at:

```
    https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app
```

Answer (score 1):

run `bokeh serve --show filename.py` to run a specific py file.

Comment: there is a mistake, correct 'bokeh serve --filename.py' as 'bokeh serve --show filename.py'